# how get value outside ui-view

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have created multiple `app`. 
My below code is running, the only problem is, I am put this piece of code in every app under `app.config`

I want to display HeadName outside `<div ui-view></div>`.

Is there any way, I can avoid redundant code? 
I tried writing service / factory ... but no success. Probability my service is not correct. 
Can any one help me ..

```
app.controller('headerController', function ($scope, Restangular) {
        var vm = this;
        Restangular.one('HeadName').get().then(function (result) {
            $scope.headName = result.plain();
        })

    })
```

Comment: what does ui-view have to do with this? problem is not clear. As for duplicating code, ...  wrap this in a module with it's own config block and inject that module in different apps

Comment: @charlietfl : actual main problem is duplicating code. Is it possible for you to guide me with code snipped .. for clarity